# Hive create new column on the fly and use it in SELECT

Tags: hive, hiveql

How can I define a new column on the fly and use it in the same SELECT statement?

```
SELECT 
    "a" AS colA
  , colA + "b" AS colB
```

I prefer to do it without subquery.

Comment: Why of course without subquery? Subquery itself will NOT add additional map-reduce step in this case.

Comment: I need to create a few columns in my statement and it would be unclear.

Comment: Hive does not support referencing calculated columns in the select in the same subquery, Subquery, or repeating calculation is the workaround.

Comment: You cannot create the columns on the fly. You need to create the schema as you want in the final one. You can load the data in those columns on the fly

Comment: The example probably is over-simplified

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Common Table Expression and see whether it helps.

CTE's give better clarity than subquery.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression